# Element CardDescription showing above others

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Specifically this component

```js
  const CardDetails = ({ index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={style.cardDetails} >
        <View style={style.infoContainer}>
          <Text style={[style.text, style.title]}>{data[index].name}</Text>
          <Pressable onPress={() => sheetRef.current.snapTo(0)} style={{ marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 20, marginTop: 5 }}>
            <Feather name="info" size={24} color="grey" />
          </Pressable>
        </View>
        <Text style={[style.text, style.university]} numberOfLines={6} >{data[index].price}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

is rendering above all other components in a page for some reason and I can't figure it out. The gist of the entire component and styling of that component
https://gist.github.com/MislavPeric/b388c84a8040c7085f99a64f76297f37/edit

Here's also a picture to describe the issue

[image]

The component that should render above is the `BottomSheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue laid in the `elevation` prop I passed to the container as styling. Removing the elevation it worked as intended.